# Реализовать onSaveInstanceState в Fragment. Сохранение конфигурации

Tags: fragmenttabhost, android, swipe, java, android-asynctask

Никак не могу решить проблему с сохранением конфигурации, помогите код нагуглен, с мануалами не подружился ( уже неделю не могу разобраться. Заранее спасибо!

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);               
    setRetainInstance(true);
    new connectTask().execute("");
}

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {          
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat, container, false);    
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());     
    editTextPreference = prefs.getString("editTextPref","GBR13");
    namer = editTextPreference;    
    if (namer == null){
        namer = "GBR1";}
    sound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), sound);        
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Button send = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    mList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);        
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    new connectTask().execute("");        
    IsWork = true;        
    Handlx =  new Handler();  
    new Thread(new Task()).start();  
    new connectTask().execute("");        
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {               
        String message = editText.getText().toString();           
        if (mTcpClient != null) { 
        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
        }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);     
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);          
}

public void getlist(){      
    while (IsWork){             
        mTcpClient.sendMessage(MyLocationListener.Location+"::geo");  
        try{                        
            String msg = mTcpClient.serverMessage;          
            if(msg.contains("::geo")){                  
                String[] s_geo = msg.trim().split(",");                 
                MainActivity.exel.addArray(s_geo);                  
            }else if(msg.contains("::obj")) {                   
                String[] s_obj = msg.trim().split(",");                 
                    MainActivity.exel.addArray(s_obj); 
            }else if (msg.contains("::alr")) {                  
                String[] s_alr = msg.trim().split(",");                 
                    MainActivity.exel.addArray(s_alr);                                              
                        }
            }
      catch (Exception e) {
      }         
    }
}
class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {       
             if (mTcpClient != null) {            
                 Thread.sleep(1000);                    
                 getlist();                 
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {              
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    Handlx.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

                }
            });
        }
    }
@Override
public void onResume(){     
        super.onResume();          
        new connectTask().execute("");
        new connectTask().execute("");
        new Thread(new Task()).start();        
        IsWork = true;          
    }

@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (mTcpClient != null) {
        // disconnect
        mTcpClient.stopClient();
        mTcpClient = null;
    }
    try {   
        IsWork = false;                 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

@Override
public void onDetach(){
    super.onDetach();
    if (mTcpClient != null) {           
        mTcpClient.stopClient();
        mTcpClient = null;
    }
    try {   
        IsWork = false;                 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
            super.onPause();    
            if (mTcpClient != null) {           
                mTcpClient.stopClient();
                mTcpClient = null;
            }
            try {   
                IsWork = false;                 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu1) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu1);
    return true;
}
 @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {             
           case R.id.helow:
               if (mTcpClient != null) {
                   mTcpClient.sendMessage("Всем привет");
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.dela:
                if (mTcpClient != null) {
                      mTcpClient.sendMessage("Как дела?");
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.smile:
                if (mTcpClient != null) {
                      mTcpClient.sendMessage(";)");
                    return true;
                }
                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
        }

  public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TCPClient> {

        @Override
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();              
            return (null);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
           super.onProgressUpdate(values);
           if(!values[0].contains("::geo")){
            arrayList.add(values[0]);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mp2.start();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что надо сохранить и восстановит? Это фрагмент?

Comment: да, после повторного запуска приложения соеденение не рветься но и в интерфейсе пустота

Comment: Прошу помогите, уже не знаю что и делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень мутно вопросы задаёте. Я лично ничего не понял.
Но скорее всего вы хотите восстановить запущенный AsyncTask.

1. Вы запускаете этот Task везде где можно, а лучше запустить его в одном месте.
2. У вас стоит setRetainTask, это почти точно вызовет утечки памяти.
3. При установленном setRetainTask вы пересоздаете адаптер каждый раз в onCreateView, а надо создать его один раз в onCreate.
4. Из 3го пункта выходит, что вы каждый раз запускаете свой Task на подключение к серверу и при этом пересоздаете адаптер, а затем обновляете в publishProgress убитый адаптер. Тут чёрт ногу сломит.

По текущему коду перенесите весь одноразовый код в onCreate

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {          
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList); 
        new connectTask().execute("");        
            IsWork = true;        
            Handlx =  new Handler();  
            new Thread(new Task()).start();

        if (namer == null){
            namer = "GBR1";}
        sound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), sound);

arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

В onCreateView оставьте только код, работающий с View

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat, container, false);        
    final EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Button send = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    mList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);    
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {               
        String message = editText.getText().toString();           
        if (mTcpClient != null) { 
        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
        }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

И как-то должно заработать. Думаю смысл вы поняли. И не забывайте вручную обнулять все объекты, которые могут содержать ссылку на Context текущей Activity, иначе будут утечки памяти.

А если по серьезному делать прослушку сервера, то надо использовать [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), который будет через [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) отправлять все события, а в Fragment вам нужно будет только подписываться на сообщения и обрабатывать их как нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Еще вопрос, что должно быть в onResume ??

Comment: @FreeSpell ничего, в onDestroyView тоже ничего, т.к. этот метод вызывается при каждом пересоздании View. Засуньте то, что хотите уничтожить в onDestroy.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html посмотрите жизненный цикл фрагментов.